# print out list of names passed from external file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a .txt file with a list of Names displayed like

```
Ashley
Anna
Alex
etc...
```

I want to write a script to pass this file from the command line and to print the output in the following format,

```
"Ashley" = "Ashley";
```

I'm still new to shell script, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use a `while read -r name;` loop, with its input redirected from the file.

Comment: I'm sure you should be able to find some bash scripting tutorials that show how to loop through the contents of a file. SO is not a tutoring service, you're supposed to learn the basics, try to implement it, and then post your code if you can't get it working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat names.txt
Ashley Smith
Anna Daulin
Alex de Witt
```

You would read the file one line at a time and then format as desired:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do 
      printf "\"%s\"=\"%s\";\n" "$line" "$line"
  done < names.txt
"Ashley Smith"="Ashley Smith";
"Anna Daulin"="Anna Daulin";
"Alex de Witt"="Alex de Witt";
```

Or just use `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"="\1";/' names.txt
"Ashley Smith"="Ashley Smith";
"Anna Daulin"="Anna Daulin";
"Alex de Witt"="Alex de Witt";
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you. 
What if the name had spaces, say Ashley Smith? Also can I pass the file name as an argument from the command line?

Comment: The sed version works without change. Bash version becomes `while IFS= read line || [[ -n $line ]]; do printf "\"%s\"=\"%s\"\n" "$line" "$line"; done < names.txt`. See edits

Comment: i tried the new edit but it gives me the following error in the terminal.
     line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
     line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I tried the sed command and it worked perfectly!!!

Answer (score 0):

Read the file one line at a time and pass through the below one liner to echo  the new fromat.

quote the printed out names with `\"` ... read more 
[here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)

```
[dza ~]$ line="alex" &&  echo "\"$line\" = \"$line\"" ";"
```

will print :

```
"alex" = "alex" ;
```